# How to get text sibling of element using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, text

I am scraping a site and I found this

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <b>Status:</b>ACTIVE;
      <b>Type:</b>CN - CONSTRUCTION
      <b>Added:</b>02/24/2012
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

How do I get `status`, `type`, and `added` individually?

I know I will get downvotes because I am not posting any TRIED CODE... but I cant even seem to think what to try!

This website has POOR HTML structure and I cant seem to find any way.

Comment: What is meaning of *I have the main TD as object*?

Comment: sorry, ignore that ... that is confusing ... I removed that from question ... now please see my questoin again.

Comment: I am on mobile so cannot post a solution as it's difficult to type code. I would give a basic idea. Take the td `innerHtml` now split this string by `<b>` you will end up with `Status:</b>ACTIVE;` as 0 index and `Type:</b>CN - CONSTRUCTION` as index 1 etc.. now go ahead and split each one of this by `</b>` and now from the result the string at index 1 must be your required value

Comment: @Reddy great ... I am trying now

Comment: Also you can use regex for this kind of logic.  You can just run the regex against the innerHtml to match all the text between `</b>` and `<b>` .. this will give you array of matches and all of them are the required data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Use `jQueryElement.text()` to grab all the text.
- Use `String#spplit` to split the string

```js
var text = $('#content').text();
var split = text.trim().split('\n');
split.forEach(function(el) {
  var splitAgain = el.split(':');
  console.log("Key:  " + splitAgain[0].trim() + "   Value:  " + splitAgain[1].trim());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td id="content">
      <b>Status:</b>ACTIVE;
      <b>Type:</b>CN - CONSTRUCTION
      <b>Added:</b>02/24/2012
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Javascript [`nextSibling`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/nextSibling) property get next text sibling of element. You can select `b` elements in `td` and get next text of it.

```js
$("td > b").each(function(){ 
    console.log(this.innerText +" = "+ this.nextSibling.nodeValue.trim());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <b>Status:</b>ACTIVE;
      <b>Type:</b>CN - CONSTRUCTION
      <b>Added:</b>02/24/2012
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```